# CodeDeploy allowTraffic Fails but my code is still deployed on instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am using codeDeploy and when I run it gets stuck on in progress mode. By further researching the problem I found that it fails because of the AllowTraffic script. it just says script failed. I have looked into the logs but there are no errors. Also aws documentation suggested that it may be health check problem but both my instances are healthy in my target group.

Weird thing is that the code gets deployed despite failed status.

Can someone help?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 6):

did you enable the **elastic load balancer**? If so then check your **healthcheck** settings on your ELB. If it fails on the AllowTraffic it means that it's not getting a successful return from your load balancer. **For example, you are doing redirects on your ELB. The status code will be 301. You should add this on your ELB healthcheck.**

Answer (score 2):

If AllowTraffic stage isn't passing successfully, then usually there are 2 issues-

1. Either the target group in your application load balancer is unhealthy.
2. The Target group setting in your deployment configuration is not pointing to the target group mentioned in your load balancer under the rules.

Answer (score 0):

If health check is fine you can also try to change Application Deployment Settings:

to CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime

for me CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce was failing with same error.